# What does "Blind for the last time" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Nobody (2021)* movie, Hutch says to his wife, Becca:

> Hutch: Becca, I love you, but I need you to trust me right now.
> Okay? **Blind for the last time**.

Then he sends his family away to safety before setting his house on
fire to destroy any evidence.

What does "Blind for the last time" mean?

Comment: [***Blind trust***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blind+trust&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblind%20trust%3B%2Cc0) is an extremely common metaphoric collocation for ***intensified emphatic*** trust / faith (in the complete absence of proof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His meaning is presumably that she will not see what he intends but simply has to have confidence in him.

He is asking her to take his word on trust - that it, to believe him without seeing the evidence - which is a metaphor for being blind.